# Building a real world compass for iOS in Unity3d

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I am building a cross platform compass in C# in Unity 3D, and I couldn't find a solution to get the heading of an iOS device in degrees relative to the geographic North Pole?

For Android devices the Input.compass.trueHeading works fine, but it doesn't work on iOS devices.

If it's not possible to get it in C#, is there any other way to get it in Unity?